# Get Bitcoin historical data in the interval of minutes

Tags: bitcoin

Can anybody tell me where can I download Bitcoin historical data? I'm able to find the daily price. But that is not enough for my project. It will be better if I can have the price data in the interval of minutes.

Answer (score -1):

Here you have tool that imports bitcoin blockchain data into graph database
https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=252033.0

Answer (score -2):

You can get thousands of historical datasets from https://spreadstreet.io.

All datasets are available as a **tab-delimited, CSV file**. The datasets are a mix between raw tick data, OHLCV, spreads, mining and economic statistics. They can be used for backtesting, analysis, and charting.

[Here is an example dataset](https://vault.spreadstreet.io/index.php/s/gBVWLtsd4kio3kN/download). This is from Poloniex, and is the 30 min timeframe. We have lower time frames, but the files are larger than I wanted to link in this question.

Disclaimer: I am the founder of Spreadstreet.io